# Знать(,) в чём дело

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в предложении: «Я не знаю(,) в чём дело»?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая нужна, поскольку это СПП. Главная часть - *я не знаю*, придаточная часть - *в чём дело.* Между главной и придаточной частями СПП ставится запятая.